# Physical Applications of Stokes' Theorem.

Tags: physics, stokes-theorem

I'm currently helping an undergrad do readings on differntial geometry. The student is an engineering student, and I want to explore applications of Stokes' Theorem in physics/engineering. I don't know much about physical applications of Stokes' theorem. I was hoping that someone could give me some references on these topics.

Comment: Integral of $\operatorname{rot}B$ over a surface enclosed by a wire gives $\mu_0 I$ (if memory serves correct as it's been a long time now)

Comment: Quite succinctly, all of electricity and magnetism!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83965/interesting-applications-of-the-classical-stokes-theorem

Comment: Another intuitive topic:  the Helmholtz theorem regarding fluid flow and vortex lines  (relevant to tornados)

Comment: P.S. How is this remotely differential geometry?

Comment: Papers like [this](https://jasoncantarella.com/downloads/papers/influence/deturck.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: I removed the differential geometry tag.

Comment: James Callahan's Advanced Calculus textbook gives some explanations on flux and the physical applications of Stokes' theorem in chapter 10 and 11.